# Expression for the k-th term of the sequence of the 'decimals' of natural numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the sequence

```
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,...
```

Is there a straightforward way to express the general term?  I thought about using ceiling()/least integer function but couldn't quite get it to work.  I'm thinking if I had a simple function which output the number of digits in the natural number passed as an argument--f(1)=1, f(22)=2, f(12345)=5, etc.--I could use that, but I can't think of any way to do that either.

Comment: $$a_n = n10^{\lceil\lg(n+1)\rceil}$$ is close but obviously doesn't work. I doubt that there is anything short and simple that is much better. It's worth noting that it probably isn't particularly interesting to know this and you won't get much out of finding a closed form (other than a useless closed form).

Comment: Brian's answer managed to determine the general term, but my plan was to use it in showing that the sequence does not converge.  The idea being that such an expression would help me choose a nice epsilon that would make it work.  Might be a bit off topic now for this question, but have you any better ideas for showing that it doesn't converge?  Formally, I mean; it's 'obvious' from inspection that it doesn't converge.

Comment: Suppose it converges to $\ell.$ Then for any $N,$ you can find $n\ge N$ such that (say) $|a_n-\ell|>\frac1{10}.$ It is sufficient to do this just for e.g. $N=10, 100, 1000, \dots$

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had the idea to use Cauchy sequence iff convergent before I checked back here.  For anyone else reading: loosely speaking, it's not Cauchy since we can eventually find two consecutive terms which are at least 0.9-0.1=0.8 apart.  So choose any epsilon < 0.8 and the result follows.  Of course Dan's method works too and is the less roundabout way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of digits in the usual decimal representation of $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ is $\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1$. The integer $n$ has $d$ digits if and only if $10^{d-1}\le n<10^d$, i.e., $d-1\le\log_{10}n<d$, which is precisely what it means for $\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor$ to be $d-1$. Thus, you want

$$a_n=\frac{n}{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1}}\;.$$